# Intuos Pro Medium or Large for an architect

Tags: hardware-recommendation, drawing-tablet, wacom

I'm an architecture student. I draw, design and render with Copic markers and I also have a part time job designing logos and catalogs. I use a 24 inch monitor.

Now I want to buy a Wacom Intuos Pro, and I can't choose between medium and large. Initially I wanted to buy the large one, but I've heard it's way too big. Personally, I think the active area on the medium one is not enough. I really dont know what to do – please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you've found that the active area of the medium tablet isn't enough for your needs, and you can fit a large on your desk, then I'd say you have your answer.

Some things to consider, however:

- If you use a laptop and are likely to need to take your Wacom with you, you may find a large isn't practical. A medium Wacom is pretty much the same size as a 15" laptop, which makes it very easy to carry as part of your kit.
- If you're used to using a large tablet and you go to use a medium, no doubt it will feel a bit small. Given time, however, you will adjust to the new size and to making smaller movements with the pen, and it will just be what you're used to.

For what it's worth, I have a medium Intuos Pro and I love it.

Comment: Please consider posting this Answer on the Question that this was marked a duplicate of.